# Inverse Lognormal function in SQL

Tags: sql, function, math, logging, inverse

I have a process built in Excel and am trying to transfer it over to SQL for efficiency purposes. I have figured much of it out, including random number generation and pieces involving exponential distributions.

The one piece I am unable to figure out in SQL is how to get the inverse of lognormal.

This is how the formula looks in Excel:

```vb
    lognorm.inv(p,mu,sigma)
```

I have the equivalent to `p`, `mu` and `sigma` set up in my data and am trying to find the SQL equivalent (or workaround) to the `lognorm.inv()` Excel function.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: My apologies. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012. Data is just, for example, 10 rows with three columns. Column 1 are random numbers between 0 and 1, column 2 is the mu parameter and column 3 is the sigma parameter. I am trying to find the inverse of the lognormal function, where the random numbers represent F(x) and I am trying to solve for x

Comment: Well, for the lognormal CDF, you can take logarithms to get an equivalent problem for the normal CDF. Then the problem is finding the inverse of the normal CDF -- I don't know if that's built-in for MS SQL Server.